# Parsing Log Files with sed -e. Need to count unique class names

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a file, let's call it filename.log, in it I have something like this

```
(2014-11-18 14:09:21,766), , xxxxxx.local, EventSystem, DEBUG FtpsFile delay secs is 5 [pool-3-thread-7] 
(2014-11-18 14:09:21,781), , xxxxxx.local, EventSystem, DEBUG FtpsFile disconnected from ftp server [pool-3-thread-7] 
(2014-11-18 14:09:21,798), , xxxxxx.local, EventSystem, DEBUG FtpsFile FTP File  Process@serverStatus on exit  - 113 [pool-3-thread-7] 
(2014-11-18 14:09:21,798), , xxxxxx.local, EventSystem, DEBUG FtpsFile FTP File  Process@serverStatus on exit  - 114 [pool-3-thread-7] 
(2014-11-18 14:09:21,799), , xxxxxx.local, EventSystem, DEBUG JobQueue $_Runnable Finally of consume() :: [pool-3-thread-7]
```

I am trying to find the classes the produce the most frequent DEBUG messages.

In this example you can see *FtpsFile* and *JobQueue* are two of the classes producing a message.

I have this

```
cat filename.log | sed -n -e 's/^.*\(DEBUG \)/\1/p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10
```

This will produce the class name and show me the most frequent classes as a top 10.

The problem is this does not give me the count of the class *FtpsFile* as 4.  It counts each FtpsFile log file as a different unique entity.

How do I change the command above to basically say grab the first word after DEBUG and ignore the rest for your count?

Ideally I should get 
4 FtpsFile
1 JobQueue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With GNU `sed`:

  ```
  sed 's/.*DEBUG \(\w*\).*/\1/' | uniq -c
        4 FtpsFile
        1 JobQueue
  ```
- With `grep`:

  ```
  grep -Po 'DEBUG \K\w+' | uniq -c
        4 FtpsFile
        1 JobQueue
  ```
- With `awk`:

  ```
  awk '$6=="DEBUG"{print $7}' | uniq -c
        4 FtpsFile
        1 JobQueue
  ```

The last one can be done in pure `awk`, but for a sake of similarity I piped it to `uniq`.

Comment: `cat filename.log | sed -n -e 's/.*DEBUG \(\w*\).*/\1/p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10`

Is what did it.  

The first sort put all the classes together and then counted the uniques, sorted them and printed the top 10.

Without the first sort I was getting the result but it looked like this:
`3078 XXXHandler
3075 XXXHandler
3027 XXXXEventHandler
36 YYYYEventHandler
26 LLLEventHandler`

With the double short all _XXXHandler_ where counted together

Comment: @wiredniko yes, if your "classes" don't come grouped together as in the example from the question then yes - first `sort` before `uniq` is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix - I added the following cut command to single out that field:

```
[host:~]$ cat logfile | cut -d" " -f7 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10
      4 FtpsFile
      1 JobQueue
```

In my eagerness to K.I.S.S., this doesn't apply to classes with a space in the name.

Comment: Where is the sed expression part?  Is it before the cut -d" " -f7?

`cat filename.log | sed -n -e 's/^.*\(DEBUG \)/\1/p' | cut -d" " -f7 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10`

Gives me the number of unique words but it does not look at the class names

Comment: err, instead of "added" I should have said "replaced".

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk(instead of sed) to avoid looking at fields before the one you are interested in, then cut the section you want to see out:

```
[hunter@apollo: ~]$ cat filename.log | awk -F, '{ print $6 }' | cut -c 1-15 | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10
      4  DEBUG FtpsFile
      1  DEBUG JobQueue
```

(Note: you were also sorting twice, which seems unneeded)

EDIT: If you don't know how long the classes will be, you can add an additional awk command (instead of cut):

```
[hunter@apollo: ~]$ cat filename.log | awk -F, '{ print $6 }' | awk '{ print $1, $2 }' | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10
      4 DEBUG FtpsFile
      1 DEBUG JobQueue
```

Comment: The problem with this is I don't know how long my class name is going to be.  Also It won't always be the 6th word

Comment: See my edit above.